# ShowDialog using invoke is making the application unresponsive

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, invoke, showdialog

I'm using `Control.Invoke()` to show a dialog. The code is a handler to get credentials from the user and it can be execute in a thread, this is the reason I perform the call into an `InvokeRequired/Invoke` snippet.

Sometimes, and only in some machines, when I close the dialog, the application becomes unresposive (it does not manage some mouse clicks, but manage others). If I execute some "allowed" actions, the application start to be responsive again. It seems that processing any event, the application fixes itself.

Do you know any known bug in the .NET framework, or something that could cause this issue?

Thanks in advance.

---

**EDIT**: This is the code I'm using:

```
public class GuiCredentialsHandler
{
    // control used to invoke if needed
    private static Control mInvokeControl;

    // control used as parent for showDialog (could be null)
    private static Control mParentControl;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initialize a GetCredentials handler for current process.
    /// This method should be always called from the UI thread, for
    /// a correctly handling for invokes (when the handler is called
    /// from a thread).
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="parentControl">Application top form. 
    /// Can be null if unknown</param>
    public static void Initialize(Control parentControl)
    {
        if (parentControl != null)
        {
            mInvokeControl = parentControl;
        }
        else
        {
            mInvokeControl = new Control();
            // force to create window handle
            // otherwise, invoke required always
            // return false
            mInvokeControl.CreateControl();
        }

        mParentControl = parentControl;
    }

    public static Credentials GetCredentials(
        string servername, SEIDWorkingMode serverWorkingMode)
    {
        if (mInvokeControl.InvokeRequired)
        {
            return mInvokeControl.Invoke(
                new GetCredentialsDelegate(DoGetCredentials),
                new object[] { servername, serverWorkingMode })
            as Credentials;
        }
        else
        {
            return DoGetCredentials(servername, serverWorkingMode);
        }
    }

    private static Credentials DoGetCredentials(
        string servername, SEIDWorkingMode serverWorkingMode)
    {

        GetCredentialsDialog dialog = new GetCredentialsDialog();

        dialog.Server = servername;
        dialog.WorkingMode = serverWorkingMode;

        DialogResult result = dialog.ShowDialog(mParentControl);

        if (result == DialogResult.Cancel) return null;

        UserInfoRetriever retriever = new UserInfoRetriever(
            servername, serverWorkingMode,
            dialog.UserName, dialog.Password);

        SEID seid = retriever.GetCurrentUser();

        return new Credentials(seid, serverWorkingMode);
}

public delegate Credentials GetCredentialsDelegate(
    string serverName,
    SEIDWorkingMode mode);
```

Comment: It is unlikely its a bug.  I would post your code.  Please also describe what actions work and don't work.

Comment: @Ramhound: I have posted the source code. Thanks.

Comment: @Daniel Your GetCredentials has a Try without a Catch.

Comment: @LarsTech: sorry, I forgot deleting the try, I was calling  Application.DoEvents in a finally bloack, but this didn't fix the issue. Thanks.

Comment: Your Initialize() method is flawed.  It cannot work properly with a null argument.  Throw ArgumentNullException.

Comment: @Hans Passant: Why is flawed? Sometimes I have no parent control so I use null as parent control. The effect is the same like calling showDialog(null);

Comment: When Initialize() is called from a worker thread, the control will be created on the wrong thread.  It's Begin/Invoke() method will invoke to the wrong thread.  You want to be 100% sure that the control you use was *always* created on the UI thread.  Use Application.OpenForms[0] if you really have to. You should never have to.

Comment: @Hans: I'm 100% sure that Initialize() method is called from the UI thread. Also, this code is used by a Windows Shell extension (you don't have a parent control to pass to the method) so a new Control() is created to perform Invoke() calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is Control.Invoke actually needed in this case?

I was always under the impression that invoke was used to ensure that UI elements are accessed by the thread that **creates** the control which is usually the UI thread but does not have to be.

In this case it looks like you are trying to create a dialog from a thread and hence you should be able to update it from the thread. (Obviously you can't access it from outside your thread, which will include the main UI thread).

If I'm wrong no doubt this will get downvoted very quickly.

Comment: I use the a parent form (mParentControl) as IWin32Owner in showDialog. I need to invoke, otherwise I get an InvalidOperationException (cross thread access).

Comment: Sorry - missed the ShowDialog(mParentControl) bit.

Answer (score 0):

mParentControl will always be set equal to  parentControl even if its NULL which does not seem right.

The reason your program becomes unresposive is because your mParentControl is NULL:

```
DialogResult result = dialog.ShowDialog(mParentControl);
```

One solution around this problem is to only show the dialog if the parent is known.

```
if ( mParentControl != NULL )
    DialogResult result = dialog.ShowDialog(mParentControl);
else
    DialogResult result = dialog.ShowDialog(mInvokeControl);
```

I based my answer on the following code:

```
 if (parentControl != null)
                { 
                   mInvokeControl = parentControl;                
                }
```

I think you mean my answer makes no sense. What makes more sense that Hans Passant comment doesn't hold some truth or your code is actually correct and you discovered a bug. Since you are being rude I will just take my experience and help somebody else. Humor yourself and add code to avoid the mParentControl is Null situation because IT CAN HAPPEN. mParentControl is ALWAYS set to parentcontrol even when its NULL.

> Application top form. /// Can be null if
>   unknown

Comment: You're wrong. If I pass a null parentControl, mInvokeControl is a new Control() and mParentControl is null. Otherwise, If I pass a valid control to the Initialize() method, mParentControl and mInvokeControl will have the same reference. I need to manage both cases. Now, I'm testing the second case, I pass a control to Initialize() method, so mParentControl is never null.

Comment: @Daniel Peñalba - Did you even try my code?  Technically what you have is flawed also.

Comment: Sorry, but your answer has no sense. mParentControl is NOT NULL. I'm passing my application mainform to initialize. In this case mInvokeControl and mParentControl is the same object. Please, review the code.

Comment: @Daniel Peñalba - See my comment in my answer.